# How to parse table from html page

Tags: python, html, parsing

I'm new to python, and I've been working on this for hours to no avail...

I'm trying to extract data from a webpage and save it in a dictionary of lists so that I may present it as an enumerated list the user can select from.

The data I want is in the only table on the page and the entries each have a unique class attribute.

I've tried using SGMLParser for this task, but I honestly have no experience with it, and I think there may be a way to do this using string methods. I currently have the entire file stored in a string, but I cannot parse it to save my life. If anyone could at least point me in the right direction, I would be so thankful!

Answer (score 2):

You should check out either [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Parsing what comes back from the server is HARD.   HTML gets very wild and wooly, and frequently doesn't follow the rules.  Do not even attempt to parse this stuff yourself, use a framework to do it.  It's going to help for you to be familiar with the DOM, because a lot of these frameworks will present the parsed page to you in DOM form.  Then it's just a matter of selecting the elements you want, and getting their content.

Comment: I'd prefer to use a module that that I wouldn't have to download. So, SGMLParser or HTMLParser, but thank you! I should have specified that in the question

Comment: I understand the preference for something local, but I'm telling you you'll save yourself a lot of hassle by using something built for this purpose.  This is a pretty standard thing people want to do; there's a lot of pain rolling your own, and it tends to make for fairly brittle code.